# Finding neighbors for non adjacent polygons in R

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, nearest-neighbor, geos

I'm looking for a method or function in r-project that create a neighborhood matrix from a group of polygons that don't touch each other, like polygons of set of blocks separated by streets in a town.

I don't have a sample shapefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot really define contingency based on common boundaries (using something like spdep::poly2nb), you could use the polygon centroids to build a k nearest neighbor relationship. This will unfortunately not account for polygon size but is a good place to start.

```
require(spdep)
require(rgdal)

polys <- readOGR(system.file("etc/shapes/", package="spdep"), "eire")

polys.knn <- knearneigh(coordinates(polys), k=2)
 plot(polys, pch=19)
   box()
   plot(knn2nb(polys.knn), coordinates(polys), col="red", add=TRUE)
       title(main="K nearest neighbours, k=2")
```